# Mapper Mapster - How to unit test config?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, .net-6.0, mapper, mapster

I come here because i dont find the answer online :/

I would like to test my configuration of Mapster to avoid miss mapping which happens at developpement time. But i dont find how to implement that with Mapster lib.

Any clue ?

Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can unit test your mapster configuration by created a new mapper instance and adding your implementation classes of the IRegister to the config.

This code will search for IRegister interfaces and inject them into a instance of the mapster mapper.

```cs
public static class AddMapsterForUnitTests
{
    public static Mapper GetMapper()
    {
        var config = TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings;
        config.Scan(typeof(ImplementationOfIRegisterClass).Assembly);
        return new Mapper(config);
    }
}
```

And then in your unit test Arrange method:

```cs
// Arrange
var mapper = AddMapsterForUnitTests.GetMapper();
```